# What is this tiny pad that came off of motherboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard

What is this small pad that came off from my Asus N522VW laptop's mainboard?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWZiM.jpg

I noticed there's a bunch more of these on the motherboard and wherever these pads are, there's a white rectangle printed around it with an id above of it. How do I attach this back? Do I just glue it back? Does any type of glue work? Like liquid glue?
[image: pad]

Comment: Looks like a distance pad of some sort, maybe

Comment: Are these imprtant? What's gonna happen if I remove them but not put them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, they're springy grounding contacts, to prevent radio-frequency interference from leaking from the motherboard by completing a Faraday shield with the PCB and the metallized case. It's unlikely missing one of these would greatly increase noise leakage out from the PC.

If the PC operates normally without it, and you don't get interference on nearby equipment, such as a cell phone, just set the spring aside. If it *does* need to be reattached, it likely needs to be soldered, for electrical connectivity.